# Combine $request->request and $request->files arrays

Tags: php

Im posting a multipart with text and files and trying to pass data to form, but these data are separated, so I want to combine them.

```
$request->request->all()
$request->files->all()

$form = $this->createForm(ParkingType::class, new Parking());
$form->submit($INeedToPassTheCombinedArray);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    return $form->getData();
}
```

Both arrays have the same structure.

For example:

$request->request->all()

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "taxId": "asd12",
    "nationality": "england",
    "parkings": [{
        "total": 4,
        "capacity": 928,
        "places": [{
                "total": 123,
                "name": "test",
                "address": "test"
            },
            {
                "total": 123,
                "name": "test",
                "address": "test"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

$request->files->all()

```
{
    "parkings": [{
        "generalInfo": "File.pdf",
        "places": [{
                "logo": "File1.png"
            },
            {
                "logo": "File2.png"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

I want to combine then in one single array, getting this:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "taxId": "asd12",
    "nationality": "england",
    "parkings": [{
        "total": 4,
        "capacity": 928,
        "generalInfo": "File.pdf",
        "places": [{
                "total": 123,
                "name": "test",
                "address": "test",
                "logo": "File1.png"
            },
            {
                "total": 123,
                "name": "test",
                "address": "test",
                "logo": "File2.png"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

I tried using array_merge, but the result is a single array which contain 2 arrays. It is not adding the data of one array in the respective position of the other array.

I want to know if there is some method for do this automatically and elegant.

Comment: I would just use `foreach()` and put them both in another array. `array_merge()` and `array + array` have certain effects, if you use them, make sure and read what they do with duplicate keys.

Comment: I think [`array_merge_recursive()`](https://3v4l.org/8JVNC) gets close to what you want, the problem is that `parkings` is enumerated in both, so it's going to add that as another array and not merge keys with another enumerated instance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will solve your problem

```
$data1 = json_decode($data,true);// first post array
$data2 = json_decode($file,true);//second file array
foreach($data1['parkings'] as $key=>&$val){ // Loop though one array
   $val2 = $data2['parkings'][$key]; // Get the values from the other array
   $val += $val2; // combine 'em
   foreach($val['places'] as $k=>&$v){
       $val3 = $val2['places'][$k]; // Get the values from the other array
       $v  += $val3; // combine 'em
   }
 }
echo json_encode($data1);
{
 "name": "Test",
 "taxId": "asd12",
 "nationality": "england",
 "parkings": [
  {
  "total": 4,
  "capacity": 928,
  "places": [
    {
      "total": 123,
      "name": "test",
      "address": "test",
      "logo": "File1.png"
    },
    {
      "total": 123,
      "name": "test",
      "address": "test",
      "logo": "File2.png"
    }
  ],
  "generalInfo": "File.pdf"
}
]
}
```